# Cannot use @font-face with Font Squirrel conversion

Tags: css

I've been trying to add my own fonts on my Web page, but I still don't know exactly how to use the Font Squirrel conversor. I downloaded a free .ttf font, and converted it with the generator like this:

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: 'AbiteRegular';
src: url('fonts/abite-webfont.eot');
src: url('fonts/abite-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('fonts/abite-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/abite-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/abite-webfont.svg#AbiteRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Where *fonts* is the folder where I keep my .ttf files converted. And I use it like this:

```
body 
{
font-family: 'AbiteRegular';
}
```

All this configuration is in the .css file.
But the body text ignores this. Do you know why could it be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there might be problem with you font `URL`

```
url('fonts/abite-webfont.eot');...
```

OR the browser you are using do not support dynamic font .

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked in other browsers? Check in IE, Firefox, Chrome. If not even a single browser is displaying the fonts, then your folder structure might be wrong.

Do you have your folder structure this way? The css file, which contains the `@font-face` declaration (say `font.css`) should be placed in such a way that, there is a folder next to it, named `fonts` and the font files should be inside that folder.

```
/font.css
/fonts/abite-webfont.eot
/fonts/abite-webfont.woff
/fonts/abite-webfont.ttf
/fonts/abite-webfont.svg
```

This should work in all browsers, including IE 6, IE 7, and IE 8. Just make sure that the paths are correct. And also, the `body` declaration should come after the `font.css` declaration, i.e., the `font.css` should be included well before any styles.

Hope this helps! :)